# How can I use my own custom function in an sk-learn pipeline?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

I'm new to the sk-learn pipeline and would like use my own form of discretized binning. I need to bin a column of values based on the cumulative sum of another column associated with the original column.  I have a working function:

```
def dynamic_bin(df, column, weight, minimum):
    """
    

    Parameters
    ----------
    df : dataframe
    column : column to be binned
    weight : column that will dictate the bin
    minimum : minimum weight per bin

    Returns
    -------
    df : dataframe with new binned column

    """
    bins = [-np.inf]
    labels = [] 
    hold_over = []
    for i in sorted(df[column].unique()):
        g = df[df[column] == i].groupby(column).agg({weight:'sum'}).reset_index()
        
        if g[weight].values[0] < minimum:
            if hold_over is None:
                hold_over.append(g[weight].values[0])
                
            elif (sum(hold_over) + g[weight].values[0]) < minimum:
                hold_over.append(g[weight].values[0])
 
                
            elif (sum(hold_over) + g[weight].values[0]) >= minimum:
                hold_over.clear()
                bins.append(g[column].values[0])
                labels.append(g[column].values[0])
                
            
        elif g[weight].values[0] >= minimum:
            bins.append(g[column].values[0])
            labels.append(g[column].values[0])
    
    bins.pop()
    bins.append(np.inf)
    
    
    str_column = str(column)+str("_binned")
    # print(str_column)
    df[str_column] = pd.cut(df[column],
                            bins = bins,
                            labels = labels)
    

    return df
```

This is how I tried to make it a class.

```
from sklearn.base import  BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin

class dynamic_bin(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, weight, minimum):
        self.weight = weight
        self.minimum = minimum
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self
    def tranform(self, X):
        """
    

        Parameters
        ----------
        df : dataframe
        column : column to be binned
        weight : column that will dictate the bin
        minimum : minimum weight per bin
    
        Returns
        -------
        df : dataframe with new binned column
    
        """
        bins = [-np.inf]
        labels = [] 
        hold_over = []
        for i in sorted(df[column].unique()):
            g = df[df[column] == i].groupby(column).agg({weight:'sum'}).reset_index()
            
            if g[weight].values[0] < minimum:
                if hold_over is None:
                    hold_over.append(g[weight].values[0])
                    
                elif (sum(hold_over) + g[weight].values[0]) < minimum:
                    hold_over.append(g[weight].values[0])
     
                    
                elif (sum(hold_over) + g[weight].values[0]) >= minimum:
                    hold_over.clear()
                    bins.append(g[column].values[0])
                    labels.append(g[column].values[0])
                    
                
            elif g[weight].values[0] >= minimum:
                bins.append(g[column].values[0])
                labels.append(g[column].values[0])
        
        bins.pop()
        bins.append(np.inf)
        
        
        str_column = str(column)+str("_binned")
        # print(str_column)
        df[str_column] = pd.cut(df[column],
                                bins = bins,
                                labels = labels)
        
    
        return df[str_column]
```

When I try to implement it the following way, i get the error underneath it:

```
column_trans = ColumnTransformer(
    [
        ("binned_numeric", dynamic_bin(weight = 'Exposure', minimum = 1000),
            ["VehAge", "DrivAge"]),
        ("onehot_categorical", OneHotEncoder(),
            ["VehBrand", "VehPower", "VehGas", "Region", "Area"]),
        ("passthrough_numeric", "passthrough",
            ["BonusMalus"]),
        ("log_scaled_numeric", log_scale_transformer,
            ["Density"]),
    ],
    remainder="drop",
)
X = column_trans.fit_transform(df)

TypeError: All estimators should implement fit and transform, or can be 'drop' or 'passthrough' specifiers. 'dynamic_bin(minimum=1000, weight='Exposure')' (type <class 'dynamic_bin.dynamic_bin'>) doesn't.
```

I read the following but I don't really follow it.
[Put customized functions in Sklearn pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31259891/put-customized-functions-in-sklearn-pipeline)

Does anyone spot the mistake i've made?

Comment: The question you linked _is_ the answer. To use a function in a pipeline, you need it to implement `.fit()` and `.transform()`. That question shows how to inherit from the base classes provided by sklearn to make an easy class wrapper for the pipeline to utilize the function(s) in question

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm fitting in this transformation.

Comment: It looks like you're fitting bins to the data, then returning the bins or binned data. For a built-in example, see [KBinsDiscretizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.KBinsDiscretizer.html)

Comment: Question updated for more context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error itself is due to a typo in your method declaration. You implemented a function called `tranform` (note the missing 's') in your custom transformer class. That is why the interpreter is complaining that your custom transformer has not implemented `transform`.

While this will be a simple fix, you should also be aware that you have not adjusted your custom function to be used in the class you defined. For example:

- the variable `df` should be renamed to `X`
- `weight` and `minimum` are now object attributes and need to be referenced to as `self.weight` and `self.minimum`
- the variable `column` is undeclared

You will need to fix these issues as well. In regard to this, be aware that `ColumnTransformer` will only pass the subset of columns to the transformer that is meant to be transformed by this particular transformer. That means if you only pass the columns `VehAge` and `DrivAge` to `dynamic_bin` it cannot access the column `Exposure`.

Comment: Thank you.  Your answer makes sense.  Does the last point about not being able to access 'Exposure' mean it's not possible?

Comment: There are many workarounds to solve this. One solution would be to pass the 'Exposure' column to your custom transformer as well, i.e. to specify it in the `ColumnTransformer`'s step along 'VehAge' and 'DrivAge'. Then you can perform your transformation based on 'Exposure'. If you then want to remove 'Exposure' from the final dataframe, you'd drop it within your `transform` method before you return it.