# How can I use dask_ml preprocessing in a dask distributed cluster

Tags: dask, dask-distributed, dask-delayed, dask-dataframe, dask-ml

How can I do dask_ml preprocessing in a dask distributed cluster? My dataset is about 200GB and Every time I categorize the dataset preparing for OneHotEncoding, it looks like dask is ignoring the client and try to load the dataset in the local machine's memory. Maybe I miss something:

```
from dask_ml.preprocessing import Categorizer, DummyEncoder

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline

import pandas as pd

import dask.dataframe as dd

df = dd.read_csv('s3://some-bucket/files*.csv', dtypes={'column': 'category'})
    
pipe = make_pipeline(
   Categorizer(),
   DummyEncoder(),
   LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs')
)


pipe.fit(df, y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Two immediate things to address:

- You have not instantiated a distributed scheduler in your code.
- You should probably use the `LogisticRegression` instance from
  `dask-ml` rather than `scikit-learn`.

**Working Code Example**

Below is a minimal code example that works.

Note that the preprocessing functions accept only Dask Dataframes while the LogisticRegression estimator accepts only Dask arrays. You can split the pipeline or use a custom `FunctionTransformer` (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31259891/put-customized-functions-in-sklearn-pipeline)). See [this open Dask issue](https://github.com/dask/dask-ml/issues/84) for more context.

```py
from dask_ml.preprocessing import Categorizer, DummyEncoder
from dask_ml.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer

import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask.distributed import Client

client = Client()

from dask_ml.datasets import make_classification
X, y = make_classification(chunks=50)

# define custom transformers to include in pipeline
def trans_array(array):
    return dd.from_array(array)
transform_array = FunctionTransformer(trans_array)

def trans_df(dataframe):
    return dataframe.to_dask_array(lengths=True)
transform_df = FunctionTransformer(trans_df)

pipe = make_pipeline(
    transform_array,
    Categorizer(),
    DummyEncoder(),
    transform_df,
    LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs')
)

pipe.fit(X,y)
```