# StackingClassifier with base-models trained on feature subsets

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, ensemble-learning

I can best describe my goal using a synthetic dataset. Suppose I have the following:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_features=10, n_classes=3,
                             n_informative=3)

df = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJ'))

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    df, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)

X_train.head()
         A       B           C        D         E       F          G         H       I        J
541 -0.277848 1.022357 -0.950125 -2.100213  0.883638 0.821387  1.154613  0.075376  1.176242 -0.470087
440  1.089665 0.841446 -1.701004 -1.036256 -1.229357 0.345068  1.876470 -0.750067  0.080685 -1.318271
482  0.016010 0.025488 -1.189296 -1.052935 -0.623029 0.669521  1.518927  0.690019 -0.045486 -0.494186
422 -0.133358 -2.16219  1.170989 -0.942150  1.933444 -0.55118 -0.059908 -0.938672 -0.924097 -0.796185
778  0.901954 1.479360 -2.639176 -2.588845 -0.753915 -1.650621 2.727146  0.075260  1.330432 -0.941594
```

After conducting a feature importance analysis, the discovered that each of the 3-classes in the dataset can best be predicted using feature subset, as oppose to the whole. For example:

```
class  | optimal predictors
-------+-------------------
   0   |  A, B, C
   1   |  D, E, F, G
   2   |  G, H, I, J
-------+-------------------
```

At this point, I would like to use 3 `one-ve-rest` classifiers to train sub-models, one for each class and using the class's best predictors (as the base models). And then a `StackingClassifier` for final prediction.

I have high-level understanding of the `StackingClassifier`, where different base models can be trained (e.g. `DT, SVC, KNN` etc) and a meta classifier using another model e.g. `Logistice Regression`.

In this case however, the base model is one `DT` classifier, only that each is to be trained using feature subset best for the class, as above.

Then finally make predictions on the `X_test`.

But I am not sure how this can be done. So I give the description of my work using pseudo data as above.

How to design this to train the base models, and a final prediction?

Comment: I don't think this is easily possible. `StackingClassifier` assumes all is base models as well as the meta-model are being trained with the same target; you can't get the base models to train on one-vs-rest modified targets, and it's not totally clear how the meta-model would work in that case anyway.

Comment: I also think this is not possible, as `StackingClassifier` assumes the whole ensemble predicts the same target. However, you could do the stack yourself by fitting individual estimators to each subset of your dataset and then aggregating their predictions.

Comment: If you feel that specific columns are better predictors of certain classes, wouldn't creating a decision tree/tree-based model show that? You don't need to go through all this to create a model. Also, let's say you can do this. What do you expect the model do if two of three models are equally confident that it is their class?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can programmatically do what you describe but I am not sure what would be the gain over using a simple Random Forest that internally does all this (feature subselection and fitting etc).

Here is an implementation of what you have described. I have used exactly the same base and stacking model as the ones you mentioned:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.ensemble import StackingClassifier
from sklearn.base import clone
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer

def select_columns(X, columns):
    return X[columns]


X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_features=10, n_classes=3, n_informative=3)
df = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJ'))
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)


feature_subsets = {
    0: ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    1: ['D', 'E', 'F', 'G'],
    2: ['G', 'H', 'I', 'J']
}

# Base model
base_dt_model = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=42)

#One-vs-Rest classifiers with feature subsets
classifiers = []
for class_label, features in feature_subsets.items():

    model = clone(base_dt_model)
    
    # select features, then apply the unique model
    pipeline = Pipeline([
        ('feature_selection', FunctionTransformer(select_columns, kw_args={'columns': features})),
        ('classifier', model)
    ])
    
    classifiers.append(('dt_class_' + str(class_label), pipeline))

# Logistic Regression as the metaclassifier
stack = StackingClassifier(estimators=classifiers, final_estimator=LogisticRegression())

stack.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = stack.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: Bravo! Many thanks for your answer.

Comment: The code doesn't handle the target as a `one-vs-all`. It's training on the same target with different feature subsets.

Comment: @Kinjal this is what OP described and just accepted as solution

Comment: I guess it is just an expression/explanation issue here. This contradicts the "In this case however, the base model is one DT classifier, only that each is to be trained using feature subset best for the class" which is the final wanted behavior. This is what I have proposed.

Comment: It doesn't contradict. It rather confirms. How else would there be separate important feature subsets for the same target if not by one vs rest? As mentioned by OP "After conducting a feature importance analysis, the discovered that each of the 3-classes in the dataset can best be predicted using feature subset, as oppose to the whole."

Comment: The Asker has asked a couple of variations of the question, but this one seemed specifically about one-vs-rest targets, so I agree that this doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score -2):

You need to use `make_pipeline` and `FunctionTransformer` ([check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59743367/3304969)) on top of custom functions to filter the data by the respective columns and to manipulate the target values.

Here's a demo code

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, LabelBinarizer
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.ensemble import StackingClassifier
X, y = load_iris(return_X_y=True)

# Functions to filter the X on the important features
def select_dim1(X):
    red_X1 = X[:,:2]
    return red_X1

def select_dim2(X):
    red_X2 = X[:,2:]
    return red_X2

def select_dim3(X):
    red_X3 = X[:,3:]
    return red_X3

# functions to label binarise separate classes in y
def y_0(y):
    y[y == 0] = 1
    return y
def y_1(y):
    y[(y == 0)|(y == 2)] = 0
    return y
def y_2(y):
    y[y < 2] = 0
    return y

# converting them to function transformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer
select_dim1_tr = FunctionTransformer(select_dim1)
select_dim2_tr = FunctionTransformer(select_dim2)
select_dim3_tr = FunctionTransformer(select_dim3)

select_y_0_tr = FunctionTransformer(y_0)
select_y_1_tr = FunctionTransformer(y_1)
select_y_2_tr = FunctionTransformer(y_2)

estimators = [
    ('dt1', make_pipeline(select_y_0_tr,select_dim1_tr, DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=42))),
    ('dt2', make_pipeline(select_y_1_tr,select_dim2_tr, DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=42))),
    ('dt3', make_pipeline(select_y_2_tr,select_dim3_tr, DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=42)))
]

clf = StackingClassifier(estimators=estimators, final_estimator=LogisticRegression())

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, stratify=y, random_state=42)

clf.fit(X_train, y_train).score(X_test, y_test)
```

Comment: but this is totally not what the question says.

Comment: How? You needed to stack 3 decision trees built using a subset of the training set. All 3 have separate one-vs-all targets. I just showed it differently than what you have selected as an answer.

Comment: I don't think this works, because `FunctionTransformer` can't modify `y` in a pipeline?

Comment: You are right. Will fix it.